# Convert the structure of the tree like a left aligned tree whose each node contains a down pointer and a right pointer

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

This is a question asked in interview of Amazon.
Given a binary tree as below

```
                  A
                 / \
                B   C
                   /  \
                   D   E
                  /   / \
                 F   G   H
```

Convert the structure of the tree like a left aligned tree whose each node contains a down pointer and a right pointer and looks like the below tree.

```
        A
        |
        B – C
        |
        D—E
        |
        F—G – H
```

Can anyone help me how to solve this question.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried something? It looks that for every leftmost(and the root) node you are creating a down pointer which points to the leftmost node for the next level and a right pointer which links to a list with all the nodes in the same level

Answer (score 0):

You can use modified [breadth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) to do this. You need to keep track of when you switch to new level by using frontier.

Something like this should work.

```
Queue queue = new queue();
Queue frontier = new queue(); 
queue.enqeue(root.children);
newTree.add(root);
previousLevelParent = root;
addRightPointer = false;
while (!queue.isEmpty())
    Node tmp = queue.dequeue();
    frontier.enqueue(tmp.children);
    if (addRightPointer)
        //Add this to the right of current level
        newTree.addRight(tmp);
    else 
       //Create new level in the new tree with the
       //previousLevelParent as the parent
       newTree.createNewLevel(previousLevelParent, tmp);
       previousLevelParent = tmp;
       addRightPointer = true;
    if (queue.isEmpty())
        queue = frontier;
        frontier = new queue();
        addRightPointer = false;
```